# Safari error 426 with sockjs/tornado and haproxy

Tags: safari, tornado, haproxy, sockjs

UPDATE: While I do get the same errors, my web app now works. It was related to a coding bug that could've happened in any browser. Error 426 still does exist for me though using Safari 5.1.7

Based on scanning forums and E-mail groups, I understand Safari uses an older protocol. To get around this I have done the recommended step of adding xheaders to my tornado server

```
tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, no_keep_alive=True, xheaders=True).listen(8001)
```

Here is my javascript file

```
 var sockjs = new SockJS('http://domain.com/sockjs');
```

I think it's an haproxy issue as safari works with my tornado server on my devel/localhost machine.

This is my haproxy file:

```
defaults
    mode http
    timeout client  5s
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server  5s

frontend all 0.0.0.0:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    mode http
    timeout client 120s

    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option http-pretend-keepalive

    acl is_sockjs path_beg /sockjs
    use_backend sockjs if is_sockjs
    default_backend django

backend sockjs
    balance uri depth 2
    timeout server  120s
    server srv_sockjs1 127.0.0.1:8001

backend django
    balance roundrobin
    server srv_static 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I'm new to haproxy so any tips would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Safari has supported the current version of the websocket protocol since Safari version 6, so unless you're using Safari 5 there shouldn't be version-related problems.

Comment: Tornado 4.0 dropped support for the old protocol used by Safari 5.  I recommend falling back to long polling for Safari 5, just like you'd do for proxies that don't allow websockets.